# Cannot acces to my website through my company LAN network

Tags: apache, wamp, lan

I am trying to publish a website using a wamp server v3.0.6 located on my own PC. I can access the site from my PC using the domain name "mysite.com" and ignoring the proxy for this site. The problem is that I can not access from other PCs that are on the same LAN network of the company. When I enter "mysite.com" in the browser of another PC without a proxy, an "Unable to connect" message is displayed, and with proxy, it leaves :

```
Network Access Message: The website can not be found. 
Error Code 11001: Host not found  
Background: This error indicates that the gateway could not find the IP    address of the website you are trying to access. This is usually due to a  DNS-related error.
```

The firewall of my PC is turned off.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you show us your `httpd-vhosts.conf` file please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysite.com` is a domain name. I don't know how you have managed to direct this name to your local machine (editing the `hosts` file is the simplest approach for that), but you have to make all other computers know about the name-ip pairing you have used. And you need to pair the name with an address that is visible to others (`localhost` won't do it). If you have a machine that is part of a corporate infrastructure, you might already have a canonical name for your PC, like `pc00144.yourcompany.com`. If there is no firewall on your PC or the port you are using to serve the web content is open, then all who can ping your pc should be able to connect to your site. If it is the only site in your wamp and it is not configured to use virtual hosts, than it should be connectable by IP also.

Comment: The hosts file is configured 127.0.0.1 mysite.com. But it is not in the domain of the network of the company, so the only one that can ping the site is me.

Comment: I forgot, the proxy is in the browser, the PC has no proxy configured, like the other PCs in the company.

Comment: @FrankBotelleValdes, Of course, other can't reach you with that name because it exists only on your PC. You either need to get it added into the corporate DNS server (forget it), or ask others to modify their own hosts file and add the name pointing to your real IP (not 127.0.0.1, as that is also valid only locally). Or they simply should use this later IP and forget the name.

Comment: I work, modifying the hosts file on the other PC. I will talk to the DNS server provider to add it to the server. Thank you.